# How do I say "Thank you, Captain Obvious?"

Tags: translation, culture

How do I say "Thank you, Mr. Obvious?"
Or is it "Captain Obvious"? 
Anyway, this is a slang response when someone says something that is known to the other person - and this should be obvious to the other person, too.

Comment: "Captain Obvious" is the normal term, but I think it's obvious what you mean even if you say "Mr. Obvious" :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any routine equivalent that would be globally understood. The French equivalent is *Merci, M. de la Palice* and a few European languages refer to *lapalissades*. In Spanish and Portuguese the person is Pedro Grullo, and the word *perogrullada*. In Chinese it seems to be "And Mum's a girl" (roughly "And the Pope's Catholic"). In Japanese it's just "Oh re-e-eally?"

One possibility is to refer sarcastically to Sherlock Holmes (*Dankon, Sherlock*), but you might as well translate it directly:

> *Dankon, Doktoro Evidento*
>
> *Dankon, Profesoro de Evidentaĵoj*
>
> *Dankon, Sinjoro Antaŭ-la-Nazo*